# Setting QGIS WMS character encoding

Tags: wms, legend, qgis-server, encoding

I am using the QGIS as a WMS client. I'm loading the WMS layer but the legend characters (which are in Persian language) are not displayed correctly in the Layer tab. Is there anyway I can handle the character encoding in QGIS?

[image: Data Source Manager/WMS]

[image: Layers Tab]

Comment: The legend is generated by the WMS - so please add details of what the server is and how it is configured.

Comment: The server is the QGIS Server, and the WMS URL I'm testing is: (http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=E:/test.qgz)

Comment: Please ask only in one site, here or stackoverflow. otherwise, your question may be closed. This is a QGIS-related issue. So you may want to delete the other. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65650744/how-to-set-qgis-wms-character-encoding

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works